NHibernate Partition By with Over Clause
Does NHibernate support SQL partition by with over using RANK() or ROW_Number()
Please advise how to write NHibernate query over for below .

SELECT this_.ORDERNUMBER  
    ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION by  this_.ORDERNUMBER
    ) orderline 
FROM Table1 this_ 


Nhibernate does not support SQL partition by using RANK() or ROW_Number(), you can use raw query feature of Nhibernate. in raw query you have to keep alias names same as you have in your mapped class (used for projections).
